# does usbkd windbg debug extension work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, usb, windbg

I am trying the [Windbg USB 2.0 Extensions (usbkd)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn367056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I got this,

```
kd> !usb2tree
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that   ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: usbport!_USBPORT_MINIPORT_DRIVER                ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
```

the symbol file usbport.pdb is loaded.

```
kd> lm m usbport start             end                 module name
fffff880`03da2000 fffff880`03df8000   USBPORT    (pdb symbols)        
c:\symbols\microsoft\usbport.pdb\71BCD350024D47208D5EA216690A7BFF1\usbport.pdb
```

so this is "**the public OS symbols**" that does not contain the required data type "usbport!_USBPORT_MINIPORT_DRIVER".

does it work on Windows 8? I am currently live debugging a Windows 7 VM.
experiment shows that yes, it works for windows 8.

```
kd> vertarget
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9600 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 9600.16404.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.130913-2141
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`f5e0f000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`f60d3990
Debug session time: Thu Mar 27 22:03:13.966 2014 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:05:59.427
kd> !usb2tree

UHCI MINIPORT(s) dt usbport!_USBPORT_MINIPORT_DRIVER ffffe0000142d010

1)!uhci_info ffffe00001af61a0 !devobj ffffe00001af6050 PCI: VendorId 15ad DeviceId 0774 RevisionId 0000 
    RootHub !hub2_info ffffe000016601a0 !devstack ffffe00001660050
        Port 1: !port2_info ffffe00001626000 
        Port 2: !port2_info ffffe00001626b40 

EHCI MINIPORT(s) dt usbport!_USBPORT_MINIPORT_DRIVER ffffe00001431490

1)!ehci_info ffffe00001af31a0 !devobj ffffe00001af3050 PCI: VendorId 15ad DeviceId 0770 RevisionId 0000 
    RootHub !hub2_info ffffe000016881a0 !devstack ffffe00001688050
        Port 1: !port2_info ffffe00001741000 
        Port 2: !port2_info ffffe00001741b40 
        Port 3: !port2_info ffffe00001742680 
        Port 4: !port2_info ffffe000017431c0 
        Port 5: !port2_info ffffe00001743d00 
        Port 6: !port2_info ffffe00001744840 


Enumerated HUB List
-------------------
Root Hubs:
1) FDO ffffe00001660050 PDO ffffe0000161c050 Depth 0
    !hub2_info ffffe000016601a0
    Parent HC: !uhci_info ffffe00001af61a0
    FDO Power State: FdoS0_D0                                

2) FDO ffffe00001688050 PDO ffffe00001624050 Depth 0
    !hub2_info ffffe000016881a0
    Parent HC: !ehci_info ffffe00001af31a0
    FDO Power State: FdoS0_D0                                



Downstream Hubs:


Enumerated Device List
----------------------
```

- is the symbol for windows 7 public available at all?

Comment: It seems usbkd has been introduced with WinDbg 6.3.9600, which is the version for Windows 8.1. However, that does not mean anything. It isn't even documented in WinDbg's online help (while usb3kd is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, windows 7 public symbols wouldn't have those structures. It'd work with Windows 8 and above.